# How are the generic functions and types stored in an rlib?

Tags: generics, rust

In C++, the templates can not be generated into dynamic libraries, we can only use them by header files.

In C#, generic functions and types can be interpreted by intermediate language in .NET.

Rust has no virtual machine, and the generics can be stored in the `rlib` files. How does it managed to achieve this? What is the format of rlib files?

Comment: .rlib is a format private to rustc which is prone to change at any point and has no intention of compatibility guarantees.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An `rlib` is a regular static library (built in the `ar` format) that contains additional metadata.  That metadata contains, among other things, the complete, serialised abstract syntax tree (AST) for all generics and functions marked with `#[inline]`.

It's a bit like if there was a C++ compiler that shoved a library's header files into the compiled binary, and then read them out again when linking against that library.