# Why are pub functions marked `#[inline]` not present in the compiled object file?

Tags: rust

I created a brand new crate with `cargo new a` and typed this in `src/lib.rs`:

```
pub fn xor(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a ^ b
}

#[inline]
pub fn xor_inline(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a ^ b
}
```

When I compile with `cargo build --release`, the generated `.rlib` contains only `xor` and not `xor_inline`:

```
$ gnm -D -C target/release/deps/liba-6a3c2798185fafee.rlib
gnm: __.SYMDEF: File format not recognized

a-6a3c2798185fafee.0.o:
0000000000000000 T a::xor::hf0d97103d53d3286
gnm: rust.metadata.bin: File format not recognized
gnm: a-6a3c2798185fafee.0.bytecode.deflate: File format not recognized
```

<sup>(`gnm` is GNU `nm` installed on MacOS via Homebrew.)</sup>

I have two questions:

1. Why is `xor_inline` not inside the object file? I believe its source must be present in `rust.metadata.bin` so that cross-crate inlining works, but why is the plain function not exported from the object file?
2. Is there any flag in `rustc` that I can use with `cargo rustc --release -- ...` to ensure all `#[inline]` functions are present in the object file? (Perhaps a different `--crate-type` or one of the flags under `-C`?)

(I need this because I want to inspect the generated assembly for the functions in my crate without having to remove all inline attributes or wrapping every inline function in a public non-inline function.)

Comment: Related: according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30726157/1233251), the rlib keeps a list of functions marked as inline.

Comment: *why is the plain function not exported from the object file* — I'd assume that this code is simple enough that it's **always** inlined, thus it can never be called, so there's no reason to have object code. *I want to inspect the generated assembly for the functions in my crate* — once inlined, that assembly may or may not look at all like the inlined and optimized assembly, so inspecting it before inlining may not even be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before Rust 1.13.0, native code was in fact always generated for `#[inline]` functions. This [changed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/36524) in [Rust 1.13.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1130-2016-11-10): `#[inline]` functions that are not used in the crate are not compiled into native code. The [primary motivation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/36280) for this change is that libraries that contain a lot of inline functions that they don't use themselves are much faster to compile if they aren't translated to native code at all.

The compiler still emits the function in an intermediate representation so that the compiler can inline and optimize it in other crates.

> (I need this because I want to inspect the generated assembly for the functions in my crate without having to remove all inline attributes or wrapping every inline function in a public non-inline function.)

The whole point of inline functions is to allow the compiler to emit distinct assembly code based on how the function is used. For example, an inline function that receives arguments might have their arguments participate in [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) if some arguments are constants. Sometimes, an inlined function call can compile down to zero instructions (when Rust claims zero-cost abstractions, they really mean it!), but you couldn't tell that from the non-inlined function call! Therefore, I suspect that what you want to do would just misguide you; you wouldn't be looking at the code that the compiler would actually emit when your inline function is used.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! The reason I want to see the assembly code of the function is to make sure some specific bounds check have been eliminated. I'm guessing if they're eliminated without inline, they will be eliminated with inline as well (but the reverse is not necessarily true since the surrounding code might help the compiler eliminate more checks). Is there a better way to see the standalone assembly of the function than creating a public non-inline wrapper for each function?

Comment: @Dogbert: *I'm guessing if they're eliminated without inline, they will be eliminated with inline as well (but the reverse is not necessarily true since the surrounding code might help the compiler eliminate more checks)* => what seems reasonable may not always hold; I am wondering if the order in which optimizations are applied could not prevent the elision of bounds-checking by having prior optimizations muddying the waters when the function is inlined :/